# How can i optimize this Mysql query? It has paging already ,but i didnt add here

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I need your help to optimize the query ,I am using mysql mariadb.The job of the query is to get some datas for using ui.
I set to null some datas because of example. The query is:

```html
select  q.*, 
                (case when  q.numberofcustomizations > 0 then 1 else 0 end) hascustomization, 
                concat_ws(' - ', q.productname, q.variant) productnamewithvariant 
            from ( 
            select ca.lastname, 
                oh.orderid, 
                oh.orderno, 
                oh.datecreated, 
                p.productid, concat_ws(' ', b.name, p.model) as productname, 
                (case when pv.variantid is not null then concat_ws(' / ', pv.type1, pv.type2) end) variant, 
                ifnull(concat(' / ',ml.sku), case when pv.variantid is not null then ifnull(concat(' / ',pv.sku),concat(' / ',p.sku)) else concat(' / ',p.sku) end) as sku2,(case when pv.variantid is not null then ifnull(concat(' / ',pv.barcode),concat(' / ',p.barcode))  else concat(' / ',p.barcode) end) as barcode2, 
                ml.uuid, ml.merchantwarehouseid, 
                p.sku, 
                mo.lineid as merchantorderid,  
                mo.orderlineno,mo.pending,  
                ol.quantity, ol.comment, 
                ifnull((select sum(numberofitemshipped) from merchant_order_shipment mos where mos.merchantorderlineid=mo.lineid),0) as numberofitemshipped,  
                ifnull((select sum(numberofitemshipped) from merchant_order_shipment mos where mos.merchantorderlineid=mo.lineid and mos.`status`='delivered'),0) as numberofitemdelivered,  
                ol.price, 
                ol.bundlecode, 
                concat_ws(' ',bb.name, pb.model) as bundleproductname, 
                mo.statuscode, 
                os.isopenorder, 
                os.name as status,  p.barcode, 
                p.manufactureritemcode, 
                r.fullsizeurl, 
                r.thumbnailsizeurl, 
                sa.postalcode as shipping_postalcode, 
                sa.countrycode as shipping_countrycode, 
                (select count(0) from order_line_property olp where olp.orderid=mo.orderid and olp.lineno=mo.orderlineno) numberofcustomizations, 
                (select count(0) from order_line_property olp where olp.orderid=mo.orderid and olp.lineno=mo.orderlineno and olp.value is null) numberofcustomizationrequests, 
                case when exists(select null from order_incident oi where oi.orderid=mo.orderid and oi.orderlineno=mo.orderlineno) then 1 else 0 end hasincident,  
                (ifnull((select sum(ols.price) from order_line ols where ols.orderid=oh.orderid and ols.feetypecode='shipment'),0) / (select count(distinct pm.merchantid) from order_line olm join product pm on pm.productid=olm.productid where olm.orderid=oh.orderid) ) as shippingfee,  
                (case when olg.giftfrom is not null then 1 else 0 end) hasgiftnote
            from merchant_order mo 
            join merchant_listing ml on ml.merchantlistingid=mo.merchantlistingid 
            join order_header oh on oh.orderid=mo.orderid 
            join address sa on sa.addressid=oh.addressid 
            join order_line ol on ol.orderid=oh.orderid and ol.lineno=mo.orderlineno 
            join order_status os on os.statuscode=mo.statuscode and os.isvalidorder=1 
            join product p on p.productid=ol.productid  
            join customer c on c.customerid=oh.customerid 
            join address ca on ca.addressid=c.addressid 
            left outer join product_variant pv on pv.variantid=ml.variantid  
            left outer join brand b on b.brandid=p.brandid 
            left outer join product_resource pr on pr.productid=p.productid and pr.isdefault=1  
            left outer join resource r on r.resourceid=pr.resourceid  
            left outer join order_line_gift olg on olg.orderid=mo.orderid and olg.lineno=mo.orderlineno  
            left outer join category cat on cat.categoryid=p.categoryid 
            left outer join product pb on pb.bundlecode=ol.bundlecode 
            left outer join brand bb on bb.brandid=pb.brandid 
            join (select @categoryid=NULL, @brandid=NULL, @merchantwarehouseid=NULL, @hascustomization=NULL, @iscustomizationrequested=NULL, @hassuborder=NULL) params on 1=1
            where 
                 mo.statuscode=ifnull(NULL,mo.statuscode) 
                and oh.orderno=ifnull(NULL, oh.orderno) 
                and c.customerno=ifnull(NULL, c.customerno) 
                and ca.firstname=ifnull(NULL, ca.firstname) 
                and ca.lastname=ifnull(NULL, ca.lastname) 
                and ca.email=ifnull(NULL, ca.email) 
                and ml.productid=ifnull(NULL, ml.productid) 
                and (case when @categoryid is null then 1  
                    when cat.categoryid=@categoryid then 1 
                    when cat.overcategoryid=@categoryid then 1 end) 
                and (case when @brandid is null then 1  
                    when p.brandid=@brandid and b.isactive=1 then 1 
                    end) 
                and (case when @merchantwarehouseid is null then 1 
                    when ml.merchantwarehouseid=@merchantwarehouseid then 1 end) 
                and concat(ifnull(oh.originref,'-'),' / ',ifnull(oh.originsource,'-'))=ifnull(NULL,concat(ifnull(oh.originref,'-'),' / ',ifnull(oh.originsource,'-'))) 
                and mo.pending=ifnull(NULL, mo.pending) 
                and oh.datecreated between ifnull(NULL, oh.datecreated) and ifnull(NULL, oh.datecreated) 
            ) q 
            where 
                (case when @hascustomization is null then 1 
                    when q.numberofcustomizations > 0 and @hascustomization = 1 then 1 
                    when q.numberofcustomizations = 0 and @hascustomization = 0 then 1 
                    end)  
                and (case when @iscustomizationrequested is null then 1 
                    when q.numberofcustomizationrequests > 0 and @iscustomizationrequested = 1 then 1 
                    when q.numberofcustomizationrequests = 0 and @iscustomizationrequested = 0 then 1 
                    end)  
            order by 1
```

Explain cost:
[cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOJSW.png)

I marked the problematic points in yellow.
Also I added new index for bundlecode,it fixed. But I dont know how to fix first two lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some problems!

(1) What is this??  `and ca.firstname=ifnull(NULL, ca.firstname)`.  If you don't need the test, build the query without the test.

(2) Avoid @Variables... `SET @hascustomization=NULL` then `WHERE @hascustomization = ...` will always fail.  That is, `NULL` is not equal to either 0 or 1.

Don't try to fix that, instead get rid of @variables by constructing the query on the fly.  This will [perhaps significantly] help the optimization of the query.

More specifically, get rid of

```
    join  
            (
                SELECT  @categoryid=NULL, @brandid=NULL, @merchantwarehouseid=NULL,
                        @hascustomization=NULL, @iscustomizationrequested=NULL,
                        @hassuborder=NULL
```

and then simplify

```
    (case when @hascustomization is null then 1 when q.numberofcustomizations > 0
              and  @hascustomization = 1 then 1 when q.numberofcustomizations = 0
              and  @hascustomization = 0 then 1 end
           )
```

(etc)

(3) When you get to putting the pagination back in, rewrite the query.  Having all the JOINs before doing the pagination is quite inefficient.  Instead, do the minimal effort to find the next, say, 10 IDs, *then* do the JOINs to get the rest of the info -- this time looking up only 10 items for each JOIN.

(4) After all that, start a new Question showing the revised query; I will make suggestions of indexes (often 'composite') to further improve performance.  Be sure to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` in that Question.